# Macro in c/c++ same as script in MATLAB?

Tags: c++, c, matlab

There are certainly some differences between a macro and a function

But I want to know that is it okay that we say that macros in c/c++ are same as script in MATLAB?

The difference between macro and function in c/c++ is same like the difference between script and function in MATLAB?

Comment: No, they are not.  A macro in C or C++ is something that is expanded by the preprocessor into code that is then compiled.  A script in Matlab is a program that is evaluated by Matlab's language processor.  Furthermore, a macro does not have to look like a function at all, you may as well be comparing macros to washing machines instead of functions.

Comment: Speak to *one of* C or C++ as they are different languages. The "preprocessor" is similar, but different. Remember, macros in C are expanded into the source, they are "inlined", unlike functions.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ have the equivalent of MATLAB’s scripts. They are not scripting languages. Trying to find 1:1 correspondences between such different languages is futile, you are better off learning the features of each language independently, and not trying to translate things from one to the other. It’s the same with human languages: when you learn a new language, you don’t become fluent until you stop thinking in your mother tongue and translating, and start thinking in the new language.

Comment: Script in MATLAB is much like the source inclusion in C/C++ except that you can have mutually dependent scripts but you cannot have mutually dependent or recursive inclusion.